# Match < and > on a string, but only between <code> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

There's a section of our website that's coming from a CMS; it comes as a raw html string and rendered through React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML. However, recent content is trying to include HTML code snippets (kinda like this `<pre><code><p>Quick Example</p></code></pre>`) and React is evaluating that HTML as an actual paragraph, and not showing it as a code snippet.

I understand that I need to escape the HTML entities so it's interpreted as a string, and not an HTML element. For example, if I **manually** replace `<p>Quick Example</p>` inside the string for `&ltp&gt;Quick Example&lt/p&gt;` I get what I want. What I would like to do is try to do this with a regular expression (I'm an absolute noob with regex...) and on a lot more complex scenarios.

So far, I got this:

```
/(?<=<code>.*?)(<|>)(?=.*?</code>)/g
```

What I understand this is doing, is basically match all < or > between code tags. However, this is what it matches on regexr:

[image: wrong regex match]

I think it's matching all < and > characters, but only taking into consideration the very first `<code>` and the very last `</code>`, even matching the < and > characters of the `<code>` tags in between, which is not what I want.

In this specific example, I would only like to match the < and > of the DIV tags on the string. However, I can't only match against DIV tags as there are a lot of different code snippets coming form the CMS.

Can this be done through regex?

Just in case, here's the string I'm using as example:

```
"<p>These are some HTML tags: <code>aside</code>, <code>footer</code>, <code>form</code>, <code>header</code>, <code>main</code>, <code>nav</code>, and <code>section</code>, ... this is a code snippet:</p>&#13;\n&#13;\n<pre><code>&#13;\n<div class=\"header\">&#13;\n  HEADING CONTENT!!!&#13;\n</div>&#13;\n</code></pre>&#13;\n"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are [asking for trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/219933), mate.

Comment: @MatJ :O welp... looking at alternatives! thnx

Comment: No problem, by the way, you can create a div using javascript(inside react), set the full html string as its [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), use [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) to find `Code` nodes, replace each node's [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) with its own `innerHTML`, then you can use the `InnerHTML` of the div you first created as the value to set in react. I don't know how bad is it in react's realm, but it will work.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what I ended up doing! It worked like a charm. Thanks again for following up :)